# How to check from the beginning in Windows Forms App

Tags: c#

_Changed events check it if it is changed. How can I check it from the beginning.

```
    private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
        if (dateTimePicker1.Value.Month == 2)
        {
            pictureBox1.Visible = true;
           
        }
        else
        {
            pictureBox1.Visible = false;
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. What exactly do you want to "check from the beginning"?

Comment: Add a default value to the TimePicker in the form constructor.  Then any changes will trigger the event.

Comment: dateTime shows the current date and I want the event to happen from the beginning. If we were in February, I want the pictureBox1 to be visible from the beginning

Answer (score 1):

You can call the event handler from the `constructor`, or sometimes better, the `Load` of the form:

```
private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(dateTimePicker1, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

There is also the `Shown` event called after the window first appears on the desktop.

Thus the control will be initialized as expected.

Here is the chain of calls:

- Constructor : prefered place to instantiate objects and initialize UI instances.
- Load : prefered place to create and initialize non designer UI objects or complete them like populating combobox or dataset.
- Activated : prefered place to do things each time the form is activated and get focus.
- Shown : prefered place to do things after the form is showned like open another form or show a info box.

The difference between using constructor, load or shown is mainly to have a clean code design and a smooth UI behavior.

There is no real difference between putting code in the constructor or in the load, else the reference and window handle are [created](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.created).

[Order of Events in Windows Forms (MS Doc)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/desktop/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms)